# Per query JSON serializer in Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring-data-rest

Is there any way to define a JSON serializer per query? I would like to be able to define different JSON output for some queries, something similar to this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "person")
public interface PersonJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

    @JsonSerialize(using = SimplePersonSerializer.class)
    List<Person> findAll();

    @JsonSerialize(using = FullPersonSerializer.class)  
    List<Person> findByNameOrderByCreationDateDesc(String name);

}
```

In this scenario, SimplePersonSerializer should be used to serialize a huge list of results and FullPersonSerializer only a few results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any further information it looks like you want projections. Projections define a subset of an entity's properties. The feature is not mentioned in the official documentation, but in the [release notes](https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/21/what-s-new-in-spring-data-dijkstra) for Spring Data REST 2.1.

You just need to define an interface that contains the subset of properties:

```
@Projection(name = "simple", types = Person.class)
interface SimplePerson {

  String getFirstName();

  String getLastName();
}
```

You don't have to change your repository. The only thing that changes is the URL you are calling: `http://myapp/people?projection=simple`.